# Sharing violation after opening a VS2017 project in VS/Mac 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to convert a project of mine from Visual Studio 2017 for Windows to Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.  I can open the project file and the various C# classes in my project, but when I try to compile the project, I get this error.

[image]

The same code on VS2017 for Windows compiles without an issue.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you read the error...it says sharing violation.  Meaning something else is trying to access or has access to the pdb file.  One thing you can try is to shutdown VS and the bring it back up and load your project and try again.

Comment: I did try that.  And I'm the only person with access to that file, which is why the error is confusing me.